# Using class template in another file

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue with using class template from another file. This is the template I want to use:

```
template <class T>
class test1
{
public: 
    T tmp;
};
```

It's located in file test1.h. I want to use it in file test2.h, it looks like this:

```
#include "test1.h"
class test2
{
    test1<int> t;
};
```

When I compile the code I get errors:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta70p.png)

Comment: please do not paraphrase the error. Instead post a [mcve] and the full error message

Comment: I rearanged my question, hope its better now

Comment: better yes, but still you should include the error message in the question. And make sure the error can be reproduced with the code you posted, currently they are unrelated and I doubt the error can be reproduced with the posted code

Comment: Please show the source files as well.

Comment: They are empty, no functions are declared here in the header files so no definitions are needed

Comment: The posted codes don't cause any error on compiling and the errors are related to game header not your post. So, no one can help.